# Am I reading the font information incorrectly, or does this font not support a character?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I list here an installed font that supports the character `05D0`:

```
$ fc-list :charset=05d0 | tail -n1/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansHebrew-Bold.ttf: Noto Sans Hebrew:style=Bold
```

I then list the font features:

```
$ fc-match --format='%{charset}\n' /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansHebrew-Bold.ttf
20-7e a0-377 37a-37f 384-38a 38c 38e-3a1 3a3-3e1 3f0-52f 1ab0-1ac0 1c80-1c88 1d00-1df9 1dfb-1f15 1f18-1f1d 1f20-1f45 1f48-1f4d 1f50-1f57 1f59 1f5b 1f5d 1f5f-1f7d 1f80-1fb4 1fb6-1fc4 1fc6-1fd3 1fd6-1fdb 1fdd-1fef 1ff2-1ff4 1ff6-1ffe 2000-2064 2066-2071 2074-208e 2090-209c 20a0-20bf 20f0 2100-215f 2184 2189 25cc 2c60-2c7f 2de0-2e52 a640-a69f a700-a7bf a7c2-a7ca a7f5-a7ff a92e ab30-ab6b fb00-fb06 fe00 fe20-fe2f feff fffc-fffd
```

However, I do not see that `05D0` is in any of the stated ranges. Specifically, I have these two consecutive ranges: `3f0-52f` and `1ab0-1ac0`. Is not `05D0` between those two ranges, i.e. not actually found in any supported range for this font?

I'm reading `3f0-52f` as `03f0-052f`, and `05D0` is just above (but outside) that range. Or am I reading this incorrectly?

For what it's worth, `05D0` is the Hebrew letter א and in fact, I know that the font **does** support that character. So why don't I see it in the list of supported ranges? Not to mention that the `fc-list` command returns this font as being one that supports that character specifically as well.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l

$ fc-list --version
fontconfig version 2.13.1
```

Comment: I get [different ranges](https://pastebin.com/XgHyh2av) and one of them is `5d0-5ea` (fonts-noto-core package, same fontconfig version, Debian 11). The letters are there as expected, checked with fontforge.